# Changing the color of Office UI Fabric React components

Tags: reactjs, colors, office-fabric

I am making an Office Fabric Panel in an React app, that is used as a form to create, update and delete an entity. The thing is that on the delete-panel I want the primary button to be red instead of Fabric's standard blue.

If it is possible, I am sure it is very easy, but since I am inexperienced in HTML/CSS/JS, I don't know what to do and would like a solution that uses inline CSS. I imagine that it will look something like this:

```
<PrimaryButton onClick={ this._onDelete } style={{marginRight: '8px', backgroundColor:'alert', color: 'white'}} >Delete</PrimaryButton>
```

[MS's documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/colors) doesn't help me a lot, I don't know what to import. and my good friend Google hasn't done the trick this time. I have found some answers that are close, but [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516541/change-the-color-theme-of-office-ui-fabric-react-components) is for overriding the theme of all components and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830187/how-do-you-style-a-office-fabric-react-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) doesn't tell what to import (I guess that is the missing piece for me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
```

Then you can use the following:

```
<DefaultButton
    style={{backgroundColor:'black', color:'white'}}
    text='Accept'
/>
```

It's that easy :)